# TypeError: Object of type 'OperationalError' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, flask, web-applications

I am working at a simple webpage with Python and Flask and getting this error. I have hit a roadblock and cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with the code.

The error occurs when I am trying to log in. All the other functions work as intended. Once I press the login button the error pops.

The error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Oct/2018 17:14:46] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1816, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1833, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2114, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\sessions.py", line 375, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py", line 114, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\url_safe.py", line 42, in dump_payload
    json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py", line 99, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj, **self.serializer_kwargs))
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\json\tag.py", line 296, in dumps
    return dumps(self.tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
File "D:\Programe\Anaconda\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
File "D:\Programe\Anaconda\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "D:\Programe\Anaconda\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 81, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
File "D:\Programe\Anaconda\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'OperationalError' is not JSON serializable
```

Browser error:

```
File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",line 2309,in __call__


def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    """The WSGI server calls the Flask application object as the
    WSGI application. This calls :meth:`wsgi_app` which can be
    wrapped to applying middleware."""
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

def __repr__(self):
    return '<%s %r>' % (
        self.__class__.__name__,
        self.name,



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",line 2295,in wsgi_app

        try:
            ctx.push()
            response = self.full_dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            error = e
            response = self.handle_exception(e)
        except:
            error = sys.exc_info()[1]
            raise
        return response(environ, start_response)
    finally:



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",line 1741,in handle_exception

        # if we want to repropagate the exception, we can attempt to
        # raise it with the whole traceback in case we can do that
        # (the function was actually called from the except part)
        # otherwise, we just raise the error again
        if exc_value is e:
            reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
        else:
            raise e

    self.log_exception((exc_type, exc_value, tb))
    if handler is None:



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py",line 35,in reraise

from io import StringIO

def reraise(tp, value, tb=None):
    if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    raise value

implements_to_string = _identity

else:
text_type = unicode



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",line 2292,in wsgi_app

    ctx = self.request_context(environ)
    error = None
    try:
        try:
            ctx.push()
            response = self.full_dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            error = e
            response = self.handle_exception(e)
        except:
            error = sys.exc_info()[1]



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",line 1816,in full_dispatch_request

        rv = self.preprocess_request()
        if rv is None:
            rv = self.dispatch_request()
    except Exception as e:
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    return self.finalize_request(rv)

def finalize_request(self, rv, from_error_handler=False):
    """Given the return value from a view function this finalizes
    the request by converting it into a response and invoking the
    postprocessing functions.  This is invoked for both normal



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",line 1833,in finalize_request


    :internal:
    """
    response = self.make_response(rv)
    try:
        response = self.process_response(response)
        request_finished.send(self, response=response)
    except Exception:
        if not from_error_handler:
            raise
        self.logger.exception('Request finalizing failed with an '



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",line 2114,in process_response

    if None in self.after_request_funcs:
        funcs = chain(funcs, reversed(self.after_request_funcs[None]))
    for handler in funcs:
        response = handler(response)
    if not self.session_interface.is_null_session(ctx.session):
        self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
    return response

def do_teardown_request(self, exc=_sentinel):
    """Called after the request is dispatched and the response is
    returned, right before the request context is popped.



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\sessions.py",line 375,in save_session


    httponly = self.get_cookie_httponly(app)
    secure = self.get_cookie_secure(app)
    samesite = self.get_cookie_samesite(app)
    expires = self.get_expiration_time(app, session)
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
    response.set_cookie(
        app.session_cookie_name,
        val,
        expires=expires,
        httponly=httponly,



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py",line 114,in dumps

def dumps(self, obj, salt=None):
    """Returns a signed string serialized with the internal
    serializer. The return value can be either a byte or unicode
    string depending on the format of the internal serializer.
    """
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
    rv = self.make_signer(salt).sign(payload)
    if self.is_text_serializer:
        rv = rv.decode("utf-8")
    return rv




File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\url_safe.py",line 42,in dump_payload

                original_error=e,
            )
    return super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).load_payload(json, *args, **kwargs)

def dump_payload(self, obj):
    json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
    is_compressed = False
    compressed = zlib.compress(json)
    if len(compressed) < (len(json) - 1):
        json = compressed
        is_compressed = True



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py",line 99,in dump_payload

def dump_payload(self, obj):
    """Dumps the encoded object. The return value is always bytes.
    If the internal serializer returns text, the value will be
    encoded as UTF-8.
    """
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj, **self.serializer_kwargs))

def make_signer(self, salt=None):
    """Creates a new instance of the signer to be used. The default
    implementation uses the :class:`.Signer` base class.
    """



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\json\tag.py",line 296,in dumps


    return self.tags[key].to_python(value[key])

def dumps(self, value):
    """Tag the value and dump it to a compact JSON string."""
    return dumps(self.tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))

def loads(self, value):
    """Load data from a JSON string and deserialized any tagged objects."""
    return loads(value, object_hook=self.untag)



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py",line 179,in dumps

default is controlled by the ``JSON_AS_ASCII`` configuration variable
and can be overridden by the simplejson ``ensure_ascii`` parameter.
"""
_dump_arg_defaults(kwargs)
encoding = kwargs.pop('encoding', None)
rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
if encoding is not None and isinstance(rv, text_type):
    rv = rv.encode(encoding)
return rv





File "D:\Programe\Anaconda\lib\json\__init__.py",line 238,in dumps

    cls = JSONEncoder
return cls(
    skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,
    check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
    **kw).encode(obj)


_default_decoder = JSONDecoder(object_hook=None, object_pairs_hook=None)





File "D:\Programe\Anaconda\lib\json\encoder.py",line 199,in encode

        else:
            return encode_basestring(o)
    # This doesn't pass the iterator directly to ''.join() because the
    # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
        chunks = list(chunks)
    return ''.join(chunks)

def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):



File "D:\Programe\Anaconda\lib\json\encoder.py",line 257,in iterencode

    else:
        _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
            markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
            self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
            self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
    return _iterencode(o, 0)

def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,
    _key_separator, _item_separator, _sort_keys, _skipkeys, _one_shot,
    ## HACK: hand-optimized bytecode; turn globals into locals
    ValueError=ValueError,



File "D:\Computing Science\Year 3\Software Engineering 2\Coursework\Software-Engineering-2-Coursework\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py",line 81,in default

        return http_date(o.timetuple())
    if isinstance(o, uuid.UUID):
        return str(o)
    if hasattr(o, '__html__'):
        return text_type(o.__html__())
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)


class JSONDecoder(_json.JSONDecoder):
"""The default JSON decoder.  This one does not change the behavior from
the default simplejson decoder.  Consult the :mod:`json` documentation



File "D:\Programe\Anaconda\lib\json\encoder.py",line 180,in default

            # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

    """
    raise TypeError("Object of type '%s' is not JSON serializable" %
                    o.__class__.__name__)

def encode(self, o):
    """Return a JSON string representation of a Python data structure.

    >>> from json.encoder import JSONEncoder


TypeError: Object of type 'OperationalError' is not JSON serializable
```

The code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect,request, flash,
session, url_for
from functools import wraps

import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

import pdb

app = Flask( __name__ )
app.secret_key = "super secret key"


def SQL_Connect(db_file):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return None


# SQL_Create - Create the tables for the SQL database, only needs to be ran     once
def SQL_Create(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()

    with open('SQL.sql') as fp:
        cur.executescript(fp.read())


    def SQL_Test(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)


def SQL_GetUserByID(conn, id):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE userid = " + str( id ) )

    result = cur.fetchall()

    # I am awful code, please fix me
    return str( result[0][0] )



def SQL_Threads(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM reviews")

    rows = list(cur)

    list_of_lists = [list(elem) for elem in rows]

    for row in list_of_lists:
        AuthorID = row[4]
        AuthorName = SQL_GetUserByID(conn, AuthorID )

        row[4] = AuthorName

        return list_of_lists


def SQL_Load():
    database = "database.db"

    conn = SQL_Connect(database)
    with conn:
        # SQL_Create(conn)
        SQL_Test(conn)

    return conn


@app.route( "/SQL_AddUser", methods=["POST"] )
    def SQL_AddUser():
    Connection = SQL_Load()

    firstname2 = request.form['inputName']
    lastname2 = request.form['inputSurname']
    email2 = request.form['inputEmail']
    password2 = request.form['inputPassword']

    cur = Connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password)     VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",(firstname2,lastname2,email2,password2))
    Connection.commit()

    session['logged_in'] = True
    session['sessionEmail'] = email2

    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/index')
@app.route("/")
def index():
    Connection = SQL_Load()
    LoadReviews = SQL_Threads(Connection)

    Title = LoadReviews[0][1]
    Date = LoadReviews[0][2]
    Rating = LoadReviews[0][3]
    Author = LoadReviews[0][4]
    Text = LoadReviews[0][5]

    return render_template( "index.html", title = Title, date = Date, rating = Rating, author = Author, text = Text )


@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    error = ''
    try:
        connection = SQL_Load()
        cur = connection.cursor()
        if request.method == "POST":

            data = cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email= (%s)",(request.form['inputEmail']))

            if request.form['password'] == data:
                session['logged_in'] = True
                session['sessionEmail'] = request.form['inputEmail']

                flash("You are now logged in")
                return redirect(url_for("/"))

            else:
                error = "Invalid credentials, try again."

        return render_template("login.html", error=error)

    except Exception as e:
        flash(e)
        error = "Invalid credentials, try again."
        return render_template("login.html", error=error)


@app.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template("register.html")


@app.route("/logout/")
def logout():
    if 'logged_in' in session:
        session.clear()
        flash("You have been logged out!")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        flash("You need to login first")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I know that the code is a mess at the moment so sorry for that. I have searched everywhere and no luck.

Comment: None of these traceback errors point back to your actual code.  Can you look in the webserver error log for a meaningful message?

Comment: can you point out where that is?

Comment: That depends on your operating system and which webserver you're using.  On my Red Hat system that runs Apache, the error log is in `/var/log/httpd`, but it might be in a very different place for you.

Comment: I have added the browser error as well, maybe that would be of help. I have looked at PyCharms logs and no error is shown. Forgot to mention that the error occurs when trying to log in. All the other functions work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be two separate errors in your code, the first is in the sql within the login function and the second is within your error handling code which is why the error message you see bears no relation to the initial error. The first error is in the statement

```
data = cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email= (%s)",(request.form['inputEmail']))
```

The python sqlite3 module uses ? as a parameter placeholder not %s. The second argument to the execute function also needs to be an iterable, given that there is only a single parameter there needs to be a comma after it so that the python interpreter knows that the surrounding parentheses signify a tuple.The following code should work

```
data = cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email= ?", (request.form['inputEmail'],))
```

The error here results in an sqlite3.OperationalError which you catch with your "except Exception as e" statement. You then pass the error object directly to the flask flash function rather than a string hence the flask error message that an object of type OperationalError is not serializable. I would recommend avoiding the except Exception statement entirely and limiting exception handling to only the specific exceptions that you know could occur in that function. You can set up a custom error handler to handle all unexpected errors as per the flask documentation http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/errorpages/ which should be safer than catch all handlers in each function.